# Date parsing error in excel-interop

Tags: c#, excel, date, excel-interop

I am using excel-interop in my web application, I am trying to upload some file to my database but i have some problems regarding date format.

I have three date columns in my excel file and their format is date "dd/MM/yyyy" , two of them are parsed as odate and i can read them from the excel using the following code

```
DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(dataRow["StartDate"].ToString().Trim()));
```

the thrird column , its being read as "dd/MM/yyyy" and i check the excel file and the tree columns has same format which is date.
The Error is the value that take from third column is not represented like double ( I can not read it  like odate) it's being represented like a string "dd/MM/yyyy"
I am having parsing error .
What i can do with this column?

Comment: What is the value of that column? And what is `dataRow`?

Comment: Value something like "31/12/2014" and the datarow is a row table . I created a data table and i populate it from the excel file

Comment: What is the error message? And the value from the `double.Parse`?

Comment: Error Message is parsing Error. the value that taken from third column is not represented like double ( I can not read it  like odate) it's being represented like a string "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: But that is it's value of the `double` after parsing?

Comment: Correct , but before parsing the value which is being passed to parse function is something like "31/12/2014"